# ElasticSearch/kibana post data on console and set timestamp to now, now+1m etc without using a pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am adding some test data to an index in elasticsearch, is there some way to directly set the timestamp field to "NOW"and also do some simple math.

I have in other contexts something like {{_ingest.timestamp}} can be used, but the following does not work

post my-index/_doc {"@timestamp":"{{_ingest.timestamp}}"}

also "now" does not work post my-index/_doc {"@timestamp":"now"}

Ideally wanted to add documents quickly with something like post my-index/_doc {"@timestamp":"now"}

post my-index/_doc {"@timestamp":"now+1m"}

post my-index/_doc {"@timestamp":"now+2m"}

Can this be done without using an ingest pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ingest pipelines are very handy because they allow you to modify your source document's content, by adding a new `@timestamp` field with a dynamic value such as `{{_ingest.timestamp}}`.

However, if you don't want to use ingest pipelines, there's another way using [runtime fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime-mapping-fields.html) and a mapping script.

In your mapping, you need to define your `@timestamp` [date field with a script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html#date-params) that will compute the value of the field as the document gets indexed:

```
PUT test-date
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date" ,
        "script": "emit(new Date().getTime())"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that in the script, you're free to apply any logic you want to store `now+1`, `now+2`, etc

Then, you can index a document like you always do but without having to specify the `@timestamp` field:

```
POST test-date/_doc
{
  "field": "test"
}
```

And when you run your search, you can retrieve the value of the dynamically created `@timestamp` field, like this:

```
POST test-date/_search
{
  "_source": ["field"],
  "fields": ["@timestamp"]
}

=>

  {
    "_index" : "test-date",
    "_source" : {
      "field" : "test"
    },
    "fields" : {
      "@timestamp" : [
        "2023-03-08T14:49:50.459Z"
      ]
    }
  }
```

The big difference here is that the runtime field is created and indexed on the fly and stored as a separate field, but **your source document is not modified** like it was with the ingest pipeline. That's the biggest difference.